# Summarize points using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am trying to summarize points in a census tract and hence I used the Summarize Within tool from Pro. However, there are some points that are exactly ON the boundaries of two census tracts and I am unsure how to summarize these points. Could anyone suggest ways I could summarize these points?

Answer (score 0):

Start with select by location, selecting all points intersecting your tract, then run a summary on selected points.

Comment: Select by location "Crossed by the outline of" right?

Comment: I did try that. But, the points that are exactly on the boundary of two polygons are being assigned to those polygons. It's like there is a duplication.